# SQL Division returning odd value

Tags: sql, sql-server

So Basically I have two sum values, that I return. I then divide one of them by the other, my goal was to get spit out a basic value. However the Value that is returned is all over the place.

I assume I screwed up the "Cast" but I am not sure here.

It would be impossible for me to share the entirety of the SQL that generates this. I will focus on the end results here which start with an Outer Apply:

This is me calling the Outer apply values for display, and then my attempt at dividing them:

```
  ,VerifyBlock.Numa as [Numerator]
  ,VerifyBlock.Denominator
  ,(isNull(((VerifyBlock.Numa) / NullIF(VerifyBlock.Denominator,0)),0)) as [Division]
```

This is the outer apply that generates the above:

```
OUTER APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN CAST(tmpdc2.[14]AS decimal(10,2)) <= 0 AND (CASE WHEN T4MathBlock.[Value] >0 THEN T4MathBlock.[Value]
ELSE '0.00' END)<= 0 
THEN '0.00'
ELSE     (CASE WHEN CAST(tmpdc2.[14]AS decimal(10,2)) <  (CASE WHEN T4MathBlock.[Value] >0 THEN T4MathBlock.[Value]
ELSE '0.00' END) THEN CAST(tmpdc2.[14]AS decimal(10,2))
ELSE  (CASE WHEN T4MathBlock.[Value] >0 THEN T4MathBlock.[Value]
                ELSE '0.00' END) End)
                                        END AS [Amount]

                                    From ##TempDisclosure tmpdc2
                                     WHERE tmpdc1.[Student Number] = Tmpdc2.[Student Number]
                                     )[AF]

                     WHERE tmpdc1.[Student Number] = Tmpdc.[Student Number]
                )[VerifyBlock]
```

Sorry if the formatting is wonky.

I know the Values generated by:
VerifyBlock.Numa and VerifyBlock.Denominator are solid. The values they return are 
32747682.64 and 78740189.20 (Respectively)

The Division though returns: 947860.602435
When it should actually return: 0.4158954019886963

So where the heck did I go wrong here?

Comment: You are trying to do too many things at once.  Start again and take baby steps.

Comment: Not possible. this is the last step in recreating an Excel Sheet from hell. The SQL for this is just over 800 lines of code with 4 temp tables, a Pivot, and another few functions. Once I finish "Matching" the EXCEL, then I can refactor and make it simpler. I do not have that option as it stands right now.

Comment: Why are you ever treating a numeric (`0.00`) as a string (`'0.00'`)? Not that it is affecting your calculation (which I haven't even tried to digest), but this can be very dangerous. If it's numeric, don't put quotes around it.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't even realize I was. I am so burnt out on this project its not even funny.
I have accountants telling me that SQL can't do what EXCEL does, they are refusing to meet with me to discuss the Dept of Ed's requirements for this whole report, and honestly its just horrible. I will correct that and rerun

Comment: I fixed it myself, I found the issue. Thank you Aaron Bertrand for your help.

Comment: @user1949329 put your own solution into the answer and accept it, this will help people looking at your question realize how you fixed it.